# How do you add stroke to text in a GPU rendered Mobile app?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, text, gpu, flex4.5

My designer likes to add strokes to all her text. As this is not possible in Flash, I always just use a GlowFilter with strength 10 and quality 2 (based on this: "[How do you add a stroke to text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117393/how-do-you-add-a-stroke-to-text)")
But for a mobile application I have to use GPU rendering, because otherwise the animations are way too slow. And GPU excludes the filters. So how can I achieve stroked text in a Mobile app while using GPU?

Comment: Same question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407265/use-filters-for-text-in-gpu-mode-air-mobile.